# Samsung phone keeps restarting

Tags: factory-reset, boot-loop, reboot

I have a Samsung GT-S7273T (Android 4.2.2) and yesterday something happened while I was sleeping. After that, the phone can't stay on for more than 30~50 seconds: it hangs and then restarts itself. I've noticed that any change I make to the phone is "reverted" after it restarts (like deleting a file or switching off Wi-fi). While it is on, everything works normally (facebook, watch videos in youtube, receive notifications, even play games, etc).

I've tried booting up in Safe Mode, same thing happens. I've also tried a data wipe/factory reset through recovery mode, but when I restart the phone, everything is just like before, as if no reset was made (although it says the the data wipe was successful). I've also tried a cache wipe only, but it gives an error and restarts itself when I try.

I've also noticed that if I try to restart the phone (hold power button, tap on "Restart" option), the phone starts to switch off, showing the "switch-off animation" and then stops there, instead of restarting (but it keeps working, even receiving notifications). After a few seconds, it hangs and then restarts (just like it normally does).

The phone is not rooted and I never downloaded any custom firmware or anything like that.

Is there any other way I can force a reset on my phone?

## UPDATE

I've just tried to flash to stock ROM and then wiping data, but it seems to not have worked, although Odin reported success. All my files, apps and configuration are still there and the problem persists.

UPDATE #2

I've tried "wipe all" in shell, but it reported several errors with message "Read-only file system" and one "Permission denied".

I've also tried "wipe data", and got "permission denied" on opening /data.

Comment: This is some next level survival strategy here.

Comment: @DanB College student, can't afford even basic stuff, imagine a new phone :p

Comment: If this is a malware or trojan (No such thing as a virus for android, and its unlikely this anyway.), I give props to its maker, then take them away for doing it to the whole system.

Comment: Also, try the answer below. It may work.

Comment: @DanBrown Yep, I'm downloading the rom. From an untrusted source tho, unfortunately. Samsung doesn't provide the official rom for my device :/

Comment: If not even Odin works, then I suspect something's going on with your device's flash chip... I've seen someone else's phone exhibiting a similar problem and it appeared that his flash went into some sort of write-protection and he eventually had to send the phone back to factory replace the chip. Worse case scenario - wait and try others' answers before even considering this.

Comment: This is similar to @MattV's issue. No solution found, either.

Answer (score 1):

First solution : Since you tried both wiping all data and only the cache the only thing as far as I know left to do is to install either a backed up rom you made earlier or install a fresh official one from the manufacturer's site(samsung in your case) trough recovery mode.

Second solution: 
Try to wipe manually(this solution is assuming you use windows)

- Visit the Android Developers site to download the Android System
  Development Kit (see Resources). Right-click the ZIP archive and
  choose “Extract All.” Click “Browse” and choose your “C:\Program
  Files” directory.
- Click the folder you extracted and press “F2” to rename it. Give the
  folder a simple, descriptive name, such as “AndroidADT.”
- Right-click “Computer” in your file browser and choose “Properties.”
  Click “Advanced System Settings” and, in the System Properties
  window, click “Environment Variables.”
- Click “Path” and “Edit” in the System Variables window. When the Edit
  System Variable window opens, your path variable is selected, so
  press “End” to move the cursor to the end of the selection. If you
  type while the path is selected, you'll erase your path variable.
- Type “;C:\Program Files\AndroidADT\sdk\platform-tools\” (without
  quotes here and throughout) and ensure that you include the semicolon
  at the beginning of the path. Click “OK” to save your changes.
- Point your cursor to the upper-right corner of the screen and click
  “Search.” Type “cmd” in the Search box and click the program icon in
  the search results to launch the Command Prompt window.
- Turn on your Android phone and connect it to a USB port on your
  computer. Type “adb shell” and press “Enter.” When ADB connects to
  your device, type “--wipe_data” and press “Enter.” Your phone
  restarts in recovery mode and restores Android to factory settings.

Comment: Well, I've just tried that. Odin showed success. The problem still persists though. :(
One thing I noted is that everything is still there, even after both flashing the rom and wiping user data (all my apps are still there, files, everything). Is this how it should work? I thought that everything would have been deleted.

Comment: @andre_ss6 I updated the answer with another solution. Try it in case of a trojan which somehow prevents wiping the phone from recovery mode. If even this doesn't work you will have to send it to a service.

Comment: Well, I've just tried that (the command was "wipe all" though) and all it reported were errors "Read-only file system" and one time "Permission denied" when trying to delete the files.

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry, that was because I tried "wipe all" instead of "wipe data" only. But if wipe all didn't work, then wipe data wouldn't as well :/ 
Also, for some reason adb ins't able to connect to my device anymore.

Comment: Ok, I've tried wiping data only now, and it reported "permission denied" on opening /data

Comment: Well this is what I know I will do some research to see if I can find a sol. Sorry it didn't work so far.

Comment: What Andy Yan said is the only solution left that I can think of. You should get it's chip replaced if you don't find a solution I haven't mentioned.If you find another sol please let me know.